# Automorphism Group of Some Domain of Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one help me to find Automorphism group of

$1.$ Punctured Disk $D^*$

$2.$ Punctured Plane $\mathbb{C}^*$

$3.$ Annulas

I just know automorphism group $\{f:f(z)=e^{i \theta}\frac{(z-\alpha)}{(1-\bar{\alpha}z)}{}\}$ of $D$ which we can identify with the lie group $D\times S^1$, Automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}$ is of the form $\{f: f(z)=az+b,a\neq 0\}$ can be identified with the subgroup $P=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, a\neq 0\}$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Automorphism group of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, $\{f: f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq 0\}$ can be identified with $GL_2(\mathbb{C})/\lambda I$ where $\lambda\neq 0\in\mathbb{C}$, $I$ is identity matrix.
Thank you for help and discussion ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Edited.
If you know the automorphism group of $D$, why cannot you look at those elements
that preserve $0$? Every automorphism of $D^*$ extends to an automorpism of $D$ by the Removable singularity theorem.

Exactly the same argument applies to $C^*$, except that there is also $1/z$ automorphism. (So the general form is $f(z)=e^{i\alpha}z^k$, $k=\pm 1,$ and
$\alpha$ is real.

For the ring, you use reflection principle. By mutiple reflections in the concentric circles, every automorphism  of the ring extends to the automorphism of $C^*$.

The conclusion is that all three groups you are asking about are generated by
rotations and $1/z$. That is all isomorphic to $SO(2)$, or have $SO(2)$
as a normal subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: The same argument does not apply to $\mathbb C^\times$, since an automorphisms is not necessarily bounded near 0; consider $z \mapsto 1/z$, which is an automorphism of the punctured plane.

Comment: @feralin: Thanks, I edited.